# python class instance method call from another class instance

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, oop, methods

I have a quick question regarding python classes.
The following is the setup:
I have one class as the "mastermind" class which contains various instances of other classes. Now these classes need to call a method of that other class, but I don't know how to do that. For example:

```
class mastermind(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = hand()

    def iNeedToCallThisMethod(self, funzies):
        print funzies

class hand(object):

    def __init(self):
        pass #here should be a call to the mastermind instance's method

example = mastermind()
```

Hope you guys can help me with that, my brain is steaming! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to call mastermind's method, you need to have a reference to it.

For example

```
class mastermind(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = hand(self)

    def iNeedToCallThisMethod(self, funzies):
        print funzies

class hand(object):
    def __init__(self, mastermind)
        mastermind.iNeedToCallThisMethod('funzies')
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked fine! But doesn't it take a lot more resources if I save the Mastermind instance into the other instance? Or is it really just a reference?

Comment: In the example I've given you are not even saving the instance - the method is called on a provided parameter. But even if you did save it, it is just a reference, so there is no reason to worry about it unless you have hundreds of thousands of hands.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call `iNeedToCallThisMethod` from the `__init__` of `hand`, you should probably put the method in that class.

However, what you want to do can be achieved using a `classmethod`:

```
class mastermind(object):
   def __init__(self):
        self.hand = hand()

   @classmethod
   def iNeedToCallThisMethod(cls, funzies):
        print funzies

class hand(object):
   def __init__(self):
        mastermind.iNeedToCallThisMethod('funzies')

example = mastermind()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class hand(object):

    def __init(self, other_class):
        #here should be a call to the mastermind instance's method
        other_class.iNeedToCallThisMethod()
m_m = mastermind()
example = hand(m_m) # passes mastermind to new instance of hand
```

I'd just pass the object like above

Comment: You've got this all wrong, you need a reference between both object.

Comment: Can you elaborate I believe what I posted is correct @MalikBrahimi

Comment: `iNeedToCallThisMethod` is an instance method, so cannot therefore be called directly using the mastermind class, as you posted. `mastermind.iNeedToCallThisMethod()` would only be valid for class methods and static methods.

Comment: I believe you have mistaken that the `mastermind` was a call to the class `mastermind` but it was actually a call to a parameter being passed to the class. I should've made that clearer but the code works fine. I've changed `mastermind` to `other_class`

Comment: YES! So sorry, didn't realize that at all. The variable name threw me off

Comment: No problems, I should have coded for the viewer rather than for myself @Alejandro

Answer (score -1):

Both object need a reference to one another, try passing the instance to the constructor.

```
class Mastermind(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = Hand(self)

    def test_funct(self, arg):
        print arg


class Hand(object):

    def __init(self, mastermind):
        self.mastermind = mastermind
        self.mastermind.test_funct()
```